# Cannot validate CAPTCHA

Tags: codeigniter, captcha

*Session Class* and *URL Helper* are autoloaded.

**Controller:**

```
$this->load->helper('form');
$this->load->library('form_validation');
$this->load->helper('captcha');
$vals = array(
    'img_path' => './captcha/',
    'img_url' => base_url() . 'captcha/',
    'img_width' => '250',
    'img_height' => '50');

$cap = create_captcha($vals);
$datacap = array('captcha_time' => $cap['time'], 'word' => $cap['word']);
$this->session->set_userdata($datacap);

$this->form_validation->set_rules('captcha_image', 'Captcha',
    'required|callback_captchacheck');
if ($this->form_validation->run() == false)
{
    $datatw['image'] = $cap['image'];
    $datatw['file_view'] = "register";
    $this->load->view('home', $datatw);
} else { // }
```

**Callback:**

```
public function captchacheck($capt)
{
    $captss = $this->session->userdata('word');
    if ($captss == $capt)
    {
        return true;
    } else
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('captchacheck',
            'Security number does not match.');
        return false;
    }
}
```

It returns ***Security number does not match***.

`echo $this->session->userdata('word');` to view and copy paste but does it not work.

---

### **Error has been fixed!**

I'm sorry, I've moved:

```
$vals = array(
        'img_path' => './captcha/',
        'img_url' => base_url() . 'captcha/',
        'img_width' => '250',
        'img_height' => '50');

    $cap = create_captcha($vals);
    $datacap = array('captcha_time' => $cap['time'], 'word' => $cap['word']);
    $this->session->set_userdata($datacap);
```

to:

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() == false){
    //
}
```

and it worked well:

```
$this->load->helper('form');
$this->load->library('form_validation');
$this->load->helper('captcha');

$this->form_validation->set_rules('captcha_image', 'Captcha',
    'required|callback_captchacheck');
if ($this->form_validation->run() == false)
{
    $vals = array(
        'img_path' => './captcha/',
        'img_url' => base_url() . 'captcha/',
        'img_width' => '250',
        'img_height' => '50');

    $cap = create_captcha($vals);
    $datacap = array('captcha_time' => $cap['time'], 'word' => $cap['word']);
    $this->session->set_userdata($datacap);
    $datatw['image'] = $cap['image'];
    $datatw['file_view'] = "register";
    $this->load->view('home', $datatw);
} else
{  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the session loaded when you call the callback?

```
$this->output->enable_profiler();
```

or

```
print $this->session->userdata('word'); // inside your callback
```

It is not because sessions only work on the next server request.

Solution: pass a second parameter to the callback and do not use the session data for this.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('captcha_image', 'Captcha',
    'required|callback_captchacheck['. $datacap ['word'] .']');
```

(CI 2.1.0+ required)

Comment: <TD class="fieldLabel">&nbsp;</TD>
<TD><p><?php echo $image; ?>
<br><?php echo $this->session->userdata('word');?>
</TD>
its work in view, please help